# read columns from several file and print them in individual columns

Tags: awk

I have several text files which each one contains several columns contains numbers e.g:

```
5 10 6

6 20 1

7 30 4

8 40 3

9 23 1

4 13 6
```

I want to collect the second column of all files in separate columns. I used this code, it works but print all second columns in a single column.

```
{awk '{print $3}' > outfile}
```

How can I print each column in an individual one?

Answer (score 4):

```
$ awk '{a[FNR]=(FNR in a)?a[FNR] OFS $2:$2} 
   END {for(i=1;i<=NR;i++) print a[i]}' file1 file2 ... > outfile
```

assumes all files have the same number of lines, otherwise alignment will be off.